# What is the most simple way to set scatterplot color based on category in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to, in the most simple way, color points in a scatterplot using python. X is one column, y is another, and the last (let's say Z) has values (for example A, B, C). I would like to color the points (X, Y) using the value in Z.

I realize somewhat similar questions have been asked in the past, but this just isn't working out for me. Possibly because I had to force everything to be a float?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\......combinedsheet2.csv")

df['crowd1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['c1'], errors='coerce')
df['crowd3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['c3'], errors='coerce')
df['dist1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['d1'], errors='coerce')
```

I'm not sure why these specific values were read as anything other than floats-- everything else was, and I haven't used this command enough to know whether it messed with any future data analysis and may be the source of some pf my trouble when trying to do mixed-model analysis and such.

To plot I use:

```
df.plot(x="c1", y="d1", c="black", kind="scatter")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0, 610])
ax.set_xlim([0, 30])
```

And to plot all of my data together I use:

```
df.plot(x=["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], y=["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"], c="black", kind="scatter")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0, 450])
ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
```

Here is my csv file contents, minus a few decimal points in some cases (first 3 lines):

| bwc | c1 | d1 | dbz | c2 | d2 | lmr | c3 | d3 | tti | c4 | d4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 67.00 | F | 20.0 | 454.2 | I | 4 | 405.4 | L | 14.0 | 137.9 |
| B | 8 | 122.0 | G | 20.0 | 265.0 | J | 3 | 490 | M | 0.0 | 144.9 |
| A | 0 | 217.0 | F | 15.0 | 235.0 | I | 0 | 62.80 | N | 11.0 | 418.7 |

I would like to in each instance be able to see each different point (A, B, C, etc) as a different color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the [seaborn package](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) to do this. The first plot can be created like this:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='c1', y='d1', hue='bwc')
```

When plotting all the data together, you first need to reshape the dataframe to have the x, y, and hue variables in single columns. There is more than one way to do this. The following example uses [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html?highlight=wide#pandas.wide_to_long) which requires renaming the columns containing the letters:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd    # v 1.2.3
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.1

data = """
bwc c1  d1  dbz c2  d2  lmr c3  d3  tti c4  d4
A   12  67.00   F   20.0    454.2   I   4   405.4   L   14.0    137.9
B   8   122.0   G   20.0    265.0   J   3   490 M   0.0 144.9
A   0   217.0   F   15.0    235.0   I   0   62.80   N   11.0    418.7
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

# Melt dataframe to have x, y and hue variables in single columns
dfren = (df.rename(dict(bwc='let1', dbz='let2', lmr='let3', tti='let4'), axis=1)
           .reset_index())
dfmelt = pd.wide_to_long(dfren, stubnames=['let', 'c', 'd'], i='index', j='j')

# Plot scatter plot with seaborn
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=dfmelt, x='c', y='d', hue='let')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(8,6)
ax.set_ylim([0, 450])
ax.set_xlim([0, 20]);
```

[image: scatter_hue]